# Show error when use json in Android

Tags: android, json

I want develop Android application for one website, i fetch website posts from `JSON` and show in `RecyclerView`. I show **title**, **image**, **description** and **category** in `MainActivity` and i want when click on **Category** go to `categoryActivity` and show this category posts!
I write this codes, but when click on **Category** (for go to `categoryActivity`) show me FC error!

**Adapter Class :** i use this adapter in `MainActivity` and `CategoryActivity`.

```
public class MainAdapter_loadMore extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<MainDataModel> mDateSet;
    private Context mContext;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 7;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public MainAdapter_loadMore(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, List<MainDataModel> dataSet) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mDateSet.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.post_card_layout, parent, false);

            vh = new DataViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle()));

            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(mDateSet.get(position).getThumbnail())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image);

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getContent()));

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_dateTime.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getDateTime()));

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_author.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getAuthor()));

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_category.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getCategory()));
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = holder.getPosition();
                    MainDataModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Category_page.class)
                            .putExtra("categoryTitle", model.getCategory())
                            .putExtra("categoryID", model.getCategoryID()));
                }
            });

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = holder.getPosition();
                    MainDataModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), PostShow_page.class)
                            .putExtra("title", model.getTitle())
                            .putExtra("image", model.getThumbnail())
                            .putExtra("content", model.getContent())
                            .putExtra("dateTime", model.getDateTime())
                            .putExtra("author", model.getAuthor())
                            .putExtra("category", model.getCategory()));

                }
            });

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void add(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView main_post_title, main_post_content, main_dateTime, main_author, main_category;
        private ImageView main_post_image;

        public DataViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            main_post_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_title);
            main_post_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_picture_image);
            main_post_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_text);
            main_dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date_text);
            main_author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_name_text);
            main_category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_category_text);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AVLoadingIndicatorView progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) v.findViewById(R.id.avloadingIndicatorView);
        }
    }
}
```

for pass **CategoryID** to `CategoryActivity`, i write this code:

```
    ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = holder.getPosition();
            MainDataModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
            v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Category_page.class)
                    .putExtra("categoryTitle", model.getCategory())
                    .putExtra("categoryID", model.getCategoryID()));
        }
    });
```

**CategoryActivity codes:**

```
public class Category_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView toolbar_title;
    private ImageView toolbar_menuImage;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private MainAdapter_loadMore mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView cat_recyclerView;
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout;
    private String catTitle = "", catID = "";
    private Bundle bundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_page);
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }

        // Initializing
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.category_toolbar);
        cat_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.category_recycler);
        toolbar_title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pages_title);
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_root);
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_empty_layout);
        mAdapter = new MainAdapter_loadMore(this, cat_recyclerView, dataModels);
        // Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        }

        LoadData(catID);

        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            catTitle = bundle.getString("categoryTitle");
        }
        if (catTitle != null) {
            toolbar_title.setText(catTitle);
        }

        // Menu
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        toolbar_menuImage = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pages_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), toolbar_menuImage)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();

        // RecyclerView
        cat_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        cat_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        cat_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
        if (dataModels.size() > 0) {
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            mAdapter.setLoaded();
        }
        mAdapter.add(mainInfoModels);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (bundle != null) {
            catID = bundle.getString("categoryID");
        }

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            cat_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            cat_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public void post_back(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    private void LoadData(String catID) {
        CatDataInfo catDataInfo = new CatDataInfo();
        catDataInfo.getCatDataInfo(this, catID);
    }
}
```

**CategoryAsyncTask codes:**

```
public class CatDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP_cat.getCatIP();

    public void getCatDataInfo(Context context, String catID) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "id=" + catID);
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            String url = (String) params[0];
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            // Thumbnail
                            JSONObject images = postObject.optJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject imagesPair = images.optJSONObject("medium");
                            // Author
                            JSONObject Author = postObject.optJSONObject("author");
                            // Category
                            JSONArray category = postObject.getJSONArray("categories");
                            for (int j = 0; j < category.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject categoryObject = category.getJSONObject(j);

                                int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                                String title = postObject.getString("title");
                                String content = postObject.getString("content");
                                String dateTime = postObject.getString("date");
                                String thumbnail = imagesPair.getString("url");
                                String authorShow = Author.getString("name");
                                String categoryShow = categoryObject.getString("title");
                                String category_id = categoryObject.getString("id");

                                Log.d("Data", "Post ID: " + id);
                                Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                                Log.d("Data", "Post image: " + thumbnail);
                                Log.d("Data", "Post author: " + authorShow);
                                Log.d("Data", "Post category: " + categoryShow);
                                Log.d("Data", "Post category ID: " + category_id);
                                Log.d("Data", "---------------------------------");

                                //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                                infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(id, title, content, dateTime, authorShow, categoryShow, category_id, thumbnail));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For pass data from `AsyncTask class` to `Activities`, i use **EventBUS** .

**UPDATE**
**New AsyncTask :**

```
public class CatDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP_cat.getCatIP();

    public void getCatDataInfo(Context context, String catID) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "id=" + catID);
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            String url = (String) params[0];
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            // Thumbnail
                            JSONObject images = postObject.optJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject imagesPair = images.optJSONObject("medium");
                            // Author
                            JSONObject Author = postObject.optJSONObject("author");
                            // Category
                            JSONArray category = postObject.getJSONArray("categories");
                            for (int j = 0; j < category.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject categoryObject = category.getJSONObject(j);

                                int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                                String title = postObject.getString("title");
                                String content = postObject.getString("content");
                                String dateTime = postObject.getString("date");
                                String thumbnail = imagesPair.getString("url");
                                String authorShow = Author.getString("name");
                                String categoryShow = categoryObject.getString("title");
                                int category_id = categoryObject.getInt("id");

                                Log.d("CatData", "Cat Post ID: " + id);
                                Log.d("CatData", "Cat Post title: " + title);
                                Log.d("CatData", "Cat Post image: " + thumbnail);
                                Log.d("CatData", "Cat Post author: " + authorShow);
                                Log.d("CatData", "Cat Post category: " + categoryShow);
                                Log.d("CatData", "Cat Post category ID: " + category_id);
                                Log.d("CatData", "---------------------------------");

                                //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                                infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(id, title, content, dateTime, authorShow, categoryShow, category_id, thumbnail));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**New Logcat error :**

```
05-03 12:07:29.261 10903-12153/com.tellfa.colony E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                   Process: com.tellfa.colony, PID: 10903
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.tellfa.colony.DataAccessLayer.CatDataInfo$getInfo.doInBackground(CatDataInfo.java:69)
                                                                       at com.tellfa.colony.DataAccessLayer.CatDataInfo$getInfo.doInBackground(CatDataInfo.java:37)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
05-03 12:07:29.477 10903-10903/com.tellfa.colony E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.tellfa.colony.Activities.Category_page has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1d9cc595 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1080,1920} that was originally added here
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:376)
                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                                                                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:306)
                                                                      at com.tellfa.colony.Components.Progresses.CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(CustomProcessDialog.java:21)
                                                                      at com.tellfa.colony.DataAccessLayer.CatDataInfo$getInfo.onPreExecute(CatDataInfo.java:44)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
                                                                      at com.tellfa.colony.DataAccessLayer.CatDataInfo.getCatDataInfo(CatDataInfo.java:34)
                                                                      at com.tellfa.colony.Activities.Category_page.LoadData(Category_page.java:121)
                                                                      at com.tellfa.colony.Activities.Category_page.onCreate(Category_page.java:63)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

How can i fix this problem?

**Attention :** Please don't give me negative points, I search in google but not find answer to my question. I am amateur and I really need you helps! thanks all

Comment: Probably `i <= infoModels.size()` causing issue try to use `i <infoModels.size()` because `i` is starting from `zero`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi @ρяσѕρєяK, You've helped me so much already. please help me again . how can i edit my code and fix it? can you send me code? please please

Comment: Can u debug and check what is the content of  "postsArray"?

Comment: @Palang: change `for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {` line  to `for (int i = 0; i <infoModels.size(); i++) {` then check it's working or not

Comment: @Raghavendra, No i am amateur :( . please see my JSON link and i set for postArray from "posts" . please help me my dear friend

Comment: I suggest you to use Gson if you're allowed to integrate third party library

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, in this code not show me error! but not show me any post! :(

Comment: @CanberkÖzçelikm in this project i can't use GSON . please help me with my codes my friend

Comment: @Palang: i am sure `for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {` line causing issue. use `for (int i = 0; i <postsArray.size(); i++) {` instead of `for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {` in `doInBackground ` method

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, i edit my codes and use this code : `for (int i = 0; i <postsArray.size(); i++)` . in this code now show me FC error, but not show me any post. i meas is show nothing (white page)

Comment: @Palang: Using `for (int i = 0; i <postsArray.size(); i++)` code still getting error or not?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK,  not getting error, but not show any posts . just show empty page

Comment: @Palang: ok show JSON String which u are getting from server in `ou_response ` variable

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, can you send me true code for `ou_response` ? please . please send this code in Answer question . please

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, can you help me mydear friend?

Comment: Can u try this for a while comment this line String category_id = categoryObject.getString("id"); and try once

Comment: @Palang: dear please share json string to get more help from us bez problem u are trying to parse json string in wrong way, so without looking json string it's not possible to help more.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, are you mean from json string is json link? i update above post and i inserted all of my classes codes

Comment: @Palang can u try this change your for loop "for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {" to "for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++) {"  and try  and String category_id = categoryObject.getString("id"); to int category_id = categoryObject.getInt("id");

Comment: @Palang does it work or not?

Comment: @Raghavendra, when change for code with your codes, show me error again

Comment: @Palang same error or different? Because I parsed your json and got the result.

Comment: @Palang can u post the modified code once?

Comment: @Raghavendra, i update above post with New AsyncTask . please see it

Comment: @Palang can u post log at this time. I meant are u getting the same exception?

Comment: @Raghavendra, i inserted new LogCat. no i don't know how to getting exception

Comment: @Palang can u do one thing for a while replace (String) params[0]; with http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_category_posts&id=1 and do a Log.d of ou_response and see are you getting any data or not?

Comment: @Raghavendra, no i dont see data in logCat. for see data is use this code :`Log.d("CatData", "Cat Post ID: " + id);`  but don't show me any posts in logcat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think that you need to iterate using

`for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.size(); i++)`

instead of

`for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++)`

- Another thing is that you used `optJSONArray` where opt returns null if there is no data, use an if condition to check for that.
- Make sure that the return from the API returns successfully by providing the correct url parameters.

Comment: Thanks, i edit my `for` code with this code : `for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.size(); i++)` . how to check optJSONArray? can you send to me code? thanks

Comment: @Palang for any json object you retrieve check whether it returned null or an object, you could do that by a simple if condition : if(object != null){/*continue your code*/}

Comment: no when use `i < postsArray.size()` show me above FC error

Comment: @Palang if you've implemented the previous tips then the logcat must have changed as objects can't be null now, could you post an updated logcat ?

Comment: @Palang do you have teamviewer ?, as i need to debug.

Comment: thanks my dear friend, thanks. please wait a few for setup T.V . ok ? please

Comment: @Palang Don't forget to mark as solved, and remove the teamviewer stuff :D